# AddComponent with string in unity5

Tags: c#, unity

At runtime I want to copy one Gameobject component to another gameobject. In my case I have one camera where multiple scripts are added with values settings.

the same components i want to add into my antoher camera at runtime i have tried this so far, Getting all compoenent of an object then tryting to add but it is not working.

```
Component[] components = GameObject.Find("CamFly").GetComponents(typeof(Component));
            for(var i = 0; i < components.Length; i++)
            {
               objCamera.AddComponent<components[i]>();
///error in above line said adds a component class named/calss name to the gameobject

            }
```

Comment: you really need to stop duplicating your questions here and on stack overflow.

Comment: @UriPopov If you see cross posts, flag for moderator attention and link to the SO question in the flag message!

Answer (score 2):

Well, AddComponent's generic parameter expects a type, not a string. AddComponent actually creates an entirely new component of the given type. As far as I know there is no way to get unity to add a new component AND copy the values from another.

However, what you seem to be doing is copying ALL the components of one game object to another. If appropriate, I'd recommend just using GameObject.Instantiate, which creates a copy of an entire game object, including all it's components.

If you really need to copy components without creating a new game object, there's an answer here:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/458207/copy-a-component-at-runtime.html

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you're trying to call `AddComponent` with an object rather than a type, which is what's causing your issue. There are 3 possible ways you can fix this:

**Solution 1**
*Use AddComponent with a generic function*

This is very close to what you already have, and only requires you to use `GetType` rather than the object itself

```
Component[] components = GameObject.Find("CamFly").GetComponents(typeof(Component));
for (var i = 0; i < components.Length; i++)
{
    objCamera.AddComponent<components[i].GetType()>();
}
```

**Solution 2**
*Use AddComponent with a type as a parameter*

Very similar to the first solution, but uses `GetType` as a parameter. If you were using the return value, then you'd notice that the type returned here is `Component`, whereas the solution aboves return type is whatever you pass in to the generic function

```
Component[] components = GameObject.Find("CamFly").GetComponents(typeof(Component));
for (var i = 0; i < components.Length; i++)
{
    objCamera.AddComponent(components[i].GetType());
}
```

**Solution 3**
*Use AddComponent with a string argument*

Again, this relies on `GetType`, but uses a string instead of the type object. I haven't tested this, and my gut says it will be the slowest solution (because Unity will need use reflection to find the type you want), but is here so you can see the possible uses

```
Component[] components = GameObject.Find("CamFly").GetComponents(typeof(Component));
for (var i = 0; i < components.Length; i++)
{
    objCamera.AddComponent(components[i].GetType().ToString());
}
```

Comment: all three solution i have tried all is vain

Comment: Do you get the same error for each? Or do you get different errors/results?

Comment: Also, for copying values over, I'd definitely recomend `GameObject.Instantiate` as @Ben in their answer